# How to perform Arithmetic with ArrayList values

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I'm a beginner at using ArrayList and I want to add a number to a value stored in an element. Basically I want to do arlist(0)  += number.
here is my code (I've only pasted the relevant parts).

```
ArrayList<Integer> snakex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
snakex.add(630);
```

I'm not sure how to go on from here. I've tried:

snakex.get(0) += 5;

Doing this I get the error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".

How would I be able to change the value of snakex(0) from 630 to 635?.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are basically doing is:

```
snakex.get(0) += 5 -> 630 += 5 -> 635;
```

It does not know what to do from there. Instead do:

```
snakex.set(0, snakex.get(0) + 5)
```

The set method is defined by set(int index, Object o)
. The get(int index) gets the value at the specified index. The set(int index, Object o) sets the value at the specified index to the object.

Comment: It is still giving me the same error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". But then I  only wrote a '+' sign and it worked! Thanks

Comment: @learning2code it is a'ight. I didn't know how to at first either. Good luck though bro. CodingIsLife

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `ArrayList.get()` method which is returning an integer and when you add that value to an integer it gives error, which is rightly so. 
Now you have to use `get()` method in conjunction with `set()` method like this:

```
//index to change, so in future you don't need to 
//change whole code just change value of 'i'
int i = 0; 
snakex.set(i, snakex.get(i)+5);  //first calls the 'get()' method and then sets that value
```

[For more on ArrayList click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set()` method of `java.util.ArrayList` class to replace an existing element of ArrayList in Java. The `set(int index, E element)` method takes two parameters, first is the index of an element you want to replace and second is the new value you want to insert.

i.e.

`snakex.set(0, snakex.get(0)+5)`

Answer (score 0):

Here I am giving some example for arrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> snakex = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        snakex.add(630);
        snakex.add(640);
        snakex.add(650);
        snakex.add(660);

        for (int index = 0; index < snakex.size(); index++) {
            Integer item=snakex.get(index);//getting item for position
            snakex.set(index,(item+5)); // It is adding 5 with each item and storing tht position
        }

        // print each item using for each
        for (Integer item:snakex) {
            System.out.println(item+" ");
        }

        // delete item which value is 640
        for (int index = 0; index < snakex.size(); index++) {
            Integer item=snakex.get(index);//getting item for position

            if(item==640){
                snakex.remove(item);
            }
        }
```

For more info please [visit here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist)

Hope this will help you.

Thanks :)